# List fails to see updated state of array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

*The expected behaviour*: Two renders. Initially you see a loader and when students are successfully fetched in the background, loader changes to a list which gest populated with students.

What am I overlooking?

**Initial render**

1. use state to set `elem` to display (`<Loader/>`) and `students` array (one initial object for tests)
2. fetch `students` array of objects in `useEffect`
3. on successful fetch update state - set `students` to fetched array and `elem` to `renderList` which will populate its list items with `students` contents
4. `console.log(students.length)` shows 1 at this point - correct
5. state updated so rerender

**Second render**

6. `console.log(students.length)` shows 49 - `students` correctly updated

**WHY?** - 7. `renderList` sees initial value of `students` (1 object)

Is it because the `elem` to display and its contents (`students`) are in state and they get both updated in `useEffect` at the same time?

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

all imports

export default function AttendanceSingleClass(props) {

    const {classId, groupId} = props.route.params.classObj;
    const [students, _setStudents] = useState([{sId:1,name:'foo',fname:'bar'}]);
    const [elem, _setElem] = useState(<Loader/>);

    useEffect(() => {

            async function _getStudentsList() {
                try {
                    const students = await api.getStudentsList(groupId, classId);
                    _setStudents(students);
                    _setElem(renderList)
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            }
            _getStudentsList();
        },[classId]);

    const ListEl = (props) => {
        return (
            <View>..contents of list item...</View>
        )
    }

    const renderList = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={students}
                    extraData={students}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.sId}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <ListEl item={item} />}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

    console.log(students.length);

    return elem;
}
```

after some experiments I tried passing `students` array as `prop` to `renderList` - works. But still I don't understand why it *sees* `students` in global scope but only in initial value and not in the updated state (as shown above).

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

export default function AttendanceSingleClass(props) {

    (...)
    useEffect(() => {

            async function _getStudentsList() {
                try {
                     _setElem(renderList(students))
                } 
            }
            _getStudentsList();
        }, [classId]);

    const renderList = (students) => {
        return (...);
    }

    (...);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest choosing a different approach. It feels like a bad practice to store a component or render function in state, whilst already knowing which will be rendered when.

E.g. I like to use a `loading` state like so:

```
export default function AttendanceSingleClass(props) {
  const { classId, groupId } = props.route.params.classObj;
  const [students, _setStudents] = useState([{ sId: 1, name: 'foo', fname: 'bar' }]);
  const [loading, _setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    _setLoading(true);

    async function _getStudentsList() {
      try {
        const students = await api.getStudentsList(groupId, classId);
        _setStudents(students);
        _setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }

    _getStudentsList();
  }, [classId]);

  const ListEl = (props) => {
    return (
      <View>..contents of list item...</View>
    );
  };

  // early return the <Loader /> component when loading is true
  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={students}
        extraData={students}
        keyExtractor={item => item.sId}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <ListEl item={item} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: smart and seems far easier to follow, thanks! It still bothers me nevertheless why `students` array is not seen in its updated state;

Comment: If you could create a codesandbox or something similar, we might figure that out :-)